# Error when "Connecting Doman"

Tags: redhawksdr

In the Redhawk IDE, when I try to connect I get the following error.

Connecting Domain, has encounterd a problem

Details are 
Failed to connect 
org.omg.CosNaming.NameingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL: omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext NotFound:1.0

It does not appear that a DomainManager is getting started at all, I have the 
OmniEvents and OmniOrb running and the /etc/Omni config file set up as described in the 
documenation.

I have tried to delete and redo the DomanManger ConnnectionSettings with REDHAWAK_DEV
corbaname::localhost:2809 but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that omniNames is in a bad state, which should be resolvable through a hard reset of the service.  To do a hard reset of omniNames, you will need to stop the omniNames service, delete the files in /var/log/omniORB, and then restart the omniNames service:

```
# /sbin/service omniNames stop

# rm -f /var/log/omniORB/*

# /sbin/service omniNames start
```

Note: do not delete the omniORB directory: just delete its contents.

More details on this are in the 1.9 user manual (which may not have been available at the time of your post) in "Appendix H: Resolving omniNames/omniEvents Failures".